# How to loop through custom post type posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to display posts from a custom post type.

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'tribe_events'); foreach($args as $arg)   {
    $loop = new WP_Query( $arg );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div class="show_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; } ?>
```

This code only displays all the default posts, instead of looping through individual posts from the custom post type ""tribe_events."

Comment: not sure why that `foreach` is in there, get rid of it and just pass `$args` to your query.

Comment: @Milo Thanks! I got read of foreach, and now it's outputting the same post eight times. Why could that be??

Comment: Please [edit]  your code. If you correctly corrected the issue noted by @Milo, the code should work.